# CSS Flexbox RadioButton fields alignment

Tags: flexbox

I am trying to align the fields that are part of radio button. But it's not working.
How can I get all the fields in one line ?

```css
.container3 {
    display:flex
}
```

```html
<body>
    Suspension flag
    <div class=container3>
        <div id="suspy" >
            <input type="radio" id="suspension-flag-yes" name = "suspension-flag" value="Y">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="suspension-flag-yes"> yes</label>
        </div>

        <div id="suspn" >
            <input type="radio" id="suspension-flag-no" name = "suspension-flag" value="N">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="suspension-flag-no"> no</label>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Divs are block elements which stack on top of each other. Try removing the divs that wrap around each label and input.

Comment: it's better now, the issue that remains is the label "Yes" is appearing on the top instead of aligning with radio button. same with label "No"

Comment: When I try your code, I see radio buttons and associated fields, all 4 on the same line.

Comment: @SudhirJangam remove `class="container3"` from the `div` and/or the `.container3` in CSS. You should know fundamental HTML/CSS before using more advanced features such as `flex`.  In the layout provided, remove all `div` s then add them back in sparingly. Ex. wrap a label AND a field with a single `div`.